# ISO 8601 Repeating Intervals without Date

Tags: datetime, intervals, iso8601

With ISO8601, is there a way to specify a repeating interval which starts at a given time for any day, and repeats over time in that day?

For example, does the following hold:

`R2/T09:00:00Z/PT1H` = `R/2000-01-01T09:00:00/P1D` + `R/2000-01-01T10:00:00/P1D`?

Or is the former not correct under the standard?

The motivation behind this is to run a task at 9am and 10am every day.

Answer (score 2):

No, Iso 8601 cannot irregular repetitions.  You would need evaluate/run both of those expressions.

Cron expressions would be a better option as it is widely supported, especially for running tasks.  You can find cron expression builders on the web and a library for every language (and OS support with crontab in Unix systems).  This expression would handle your use case `0 0 9,10 ? * * *` and would run at 9 and 10 am of every day of every year.

Sorry for the response 2 years later.